# Conditionally counting elements in a column in an org-mode spreadsheet

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I'm using emacs-calc through org-mode spreadsheet and I would like to count the number of values, in a column, that are greater than a specific value (say 10).

I'm currently using emacs-calc for the computations, but if there is a solution in emacs-lisp, it would be very welcome!

I know that vcount would count the number of values in a vector, but that would count all the values in that vector. How could I add a condition so that only values > 10 are counted?

In other words, I would like a mysterious_function that would return 2 in such a case:

```
mysterious_function([2,14,11,3,9,1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, using emacs-calc, inspired by [choroba's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9177896/12892553).

```
vcount(map(<if(gt(#1,10), 1, [])>, [15,2,5,13]))
```

So, for treating a column in org-mode spreadsheet, I can do, for example:

```
vcount(map(<if(gt(#1,10), 1, [])>, @I..@II))
```

The map function is used to apply a function (an anonymous one, in that case) to each element of a vector. If the element is greater than 10, we put a 1, otherwise an empty vector.

Answer (score 5):

> How could I add a condition so that only values > 10 are counted?
>
> In other words, I would like a mysterious_function that would return 2 in such a case:
>
> > mysterious_function([2,14,10,3,9,1])

Er, you only have *one* value greater than 10 in that list - do you mean >= 10?

Anyway, I don't know about org-mode spreadsheets, but here is how to do it in Emacs Lisp:

```
(defun mysterious-function (vector)
  (length
   (remove-if-not #'(lambda (n)
              (>= n 10))
          (append vector nil))))
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, the example was badly chosen, I fixed that, thanks.
Thanks for your solution, too :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also create an additional column that will contain

```
if($2>10,1,string(""))
```

And then simply apply `vcount` on this column.

Answer (score 4):

Since the [logical operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Logical-Operations) produce 1 for true and 0 for false, we can simply [sum](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#index-vsum) the test:

```
vsum(map(<gt(#1,10)>,@I..@II))
```